# How to update 2 dropdowns based on primary dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm trying to update 2 dependent dropdowns simultaneously based on the value of the primary dropdown. Is it possible, if yes, what's wrong in my code? Correct, please.

Maybe it's better to use ASP.NET cascading dropdowns possibilites? If yes, how to do it with 3 dropdowns ?

View

```
@model RKB.Models.CountryStateViewModel

<br /><br/>
      @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
      {
      <div class="container">
          <div class="form-group">
              @if (ViewBag.CountryList != null)
              {
                  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId, ViewBag.CountryList as SelectList, "Выберите страну", new { @class = "form-control" })
              }
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateId, new SelectList(" "), "Выберите штат", new { @class = "form-control" })
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PriceId, new SelectList(" "), "Выберите цену", new { @class = "form-control", @style = "display:none" })
          </div>
          <button type="submit">Send</button>
      </div>
      }
      <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#CountryId").change(function () {
            $.get("/Home/GetStateList", { CountryId: $("#CountryId").val() }, function (data) {
                $("#StateId").empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                    $("#StateId").append("<option value='" + row.StateId + "'>" + row.StateName + "</option>")
                });
            });
        })

    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#StateId").change(function () {
            $.get("/Home/PriceList", { StateId: $("#StateId").val() }, function (data) {
                $("#PriceId").empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                    $("#PriceId").append("<option value='" + row.PriceId + "'>" + row.Price1 + "</option>")
                });
            });
        })

    });

</script>
```

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    RKBEntities db = new RKBEntities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Country> CountryList = db.Countries.ToList();
        ViewBag.CountryList = new SelectList(CountryList, "CountryId", "CountryName");
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(CountryStateViewModel csm)
    {

        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult GetStateList(int CountryId)
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        List<State> StateList = db.States.Where(x => x.CountryId == CountryId).ToList();
        return Json(StateList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public JsonResult GetPriceList(int StateId)
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        List<Price> PriceList = db.Prices.Where(x => x.StateId == StateId).ToList();
        return Json(PriceList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used the wrong property json, my friend.
For example: row.StateId => row.stateId.

Just try to modify following like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#CountryId").change(function () {
            $.get("/Home/GetStateList", { CountryId: $("#CountryId").val() }, function (data) {
                $("#StateId").empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                    $("#StateId").append("<option value='" + row.stateId + "'>" + row.stateName + "</option>")
                });
            });
        })

    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#StateId").change(function () {
            $.get("/Home/PriceList", { StateId: $("#StateId").val() }, function (data) {
                $("#PriceId").empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                    $("#PriceId").append("<option value='" + row.priceId + "'>" + row.price1 + "</option>")
                });
            });
        })

    });

</script>
```

Hope to help, my friend :))

Comment: Will try to do this. But, the first change event works for me. In the second jquery function I use Price property, because it's the name of autogenerated property by Ado. Net. Maybe something else should be changed?

Comment: @P3ar1baron: yep, maybe. You can use debugger to check the property, my friend.